# How to assign value to an object in yaml file playframework 1.2.5

Tags: java, database, playframework, yaml, one-to-one

I'm trying to make a one-to-one relationship between two tables by using playframework 1.2.5. I would like to create rating list for each user after this mapping. The java code is here:

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User extends Model {

    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String password;
    public String username;
    public Date lastlogin;
}
```

UserRating.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`userrating`")
public class UserRating extends Model {
    public double rating;    

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
    public User user;
}
```

My yaml file is like that. However, I encountered this error: Cannot parse the /conf/initial-data.yml file: mapping values are not allowed here. Could you help to fix this error?

initial-data.yml

```
- &user19 
    id: 19
    name: freud
    surname: lily
    password: x56
    username: freud
    lastlogin: 2010-05-02

- &user20 
    id: 20
    name: osman
    surname: özsu
    password: 798
    username: osman
    lastlogin: 2004-12-11


UserRating(1):
    rating: 1.2
    user: 
          - *user20
```

Comment: michael: Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax would be something like

```
User(userref):
    id: 19
    name: freud
    surname: lily
    password: x56
    username: freud
    lastlogin: 2010-05-02

# (...)

UserRating:
    id: 1
    rating: 1.2
    user: [userref]
```